# What is the best way for converting if statements into functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that returns object for payload depending on type option (it can be '0', '1' or '2'). What is the best approcach for refactoring multiple if statements into more reusable/functional way?

```
    const getPayload = type => {
        if (type === '0') {
            return {
                amount: current_amount || amount,
                type: 'TYPE_TEST1',
            }
        }

        if (type === '1') {
            return {
                percent: current_amount || amount,
                type: 'TYPE_TEST2',
            }
        }

        if (type === '2') {
            return {
                percent: current_amount || amount,
                type: 'TYPE_TEST3',
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only difference is the type. So why not simply `return { percent: ..., type: typeMapping[type] }` ?

Comment: In this specific case: `type: 'TYPE_TEST' + (type + 1)`. In general: `type: ['TYPE_TEST1', 'TYPE_TEST2', 'TYPE_TEST3'][type]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the type with the values using an object, and then just return the value for any type that you get.

```
var types = {
    0: {
            amount: current_amount || amount,
            type: 'TYPE_TEST1',
    },
    1: {
            percent: current_amount || amount,
            type: 'TYPE_TEST2',
    },
    2: {
            percent: current_amount || amount,
            type: 'TYPE_TEST3',
    }
}

function getType(type) {
    return types[type];
}
```